# What is the difference between `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` and `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus()` in the flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, uitextfield, focus, textfield

When using `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()`, there was an bug that the screen was rebuild then data disappeared.

I fixed the bug by Modify `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` -> `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus()`

but I still wonder the difference between the two code

thank you

Answer (score 2):

`FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus` property contains the currently focused focus node, which is accessible globally independently of `context`.

`FocusScope.of(context)` returns the FocusScopeNode of the FocusScope that most tightly encloses the given context. Calling this function creates a dependency that will rebuild the given context when the focus changes.